# clear part of the page fields after successfully inserted

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I would like to prompt the user saying "Do you want to enter more products?" after  successfully inserted the data into the database(on page Submit). If the user selects "Yes" then reset part of the page fields. How can this be done? I appreciate any input.

Here is my php script which works fine. But I am not sure how to use Javascript/JQuery after submit.

```
<?php 
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

            $first = $_POST["first"];
            $first = mysql_real_escape_string($first);
            $last = $_POST["last"];
            $last = mysql_real_escape_string($last);



            $insertsql = "INSERT INTO Table1(FirstName,LastName) VALUES ('".$first."', '" .$last. "')";

            $result1 = mysql_query($insertsql) or die(mysql_error());
            $new_id = MySql_Insert_Id();  


            $prodName = $_POST["prodName"];
            $prodName = mysql_real_escape_string($prodName);

            $prod_details = $_POST["prod_details"];
            $prod_details = mysql_real_escape_string($prod_details);    



$insertSQl2 = "INSERT INTO Table2(table1Id, Product_Name, Product_Details) VALUES ('".$new_id."', '" .$prodName. "', '" .$prod_details. "')";


            $Result2 = mysql_query($insertSQl2) or die(mysql_error());

    }

?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: show us what you're working with so we can suggest how to move forward.  Even better would be to try writting the script yourself and then we can help you to debug.  You won't get any useful help with such an open ended question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with javascript or jQuery.

Have your PHP set a flag once the form is submitted to be accessed later by jQuery:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        echo '<div id="submitted" data-submitted="true"></div>';
    }
?>
```

Then the jQuery:

```
function clearForm(form) {
  $(':input', form).each(function() {
    var type = this.type;
    var tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase(); // normalize case
    if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
      this.value = "";
    else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
      this.checked = false;
    else if (tag == 'select')
      this.selectedIndex = -1;
  });
};


$(function()
{
    if ($('#submitted').attr('data-submitted') === true)
    {
        var p = confirm('Do you want to enter more products?');

        if (p)
        {
            $('form').clearForm()
        } 
    }
});
```

The clear form function here was found here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data, I personally use this function quite a bit myself. Hope this helps.

Comment: I would like to clear part of the form fields. I have two sections. One is to enter customer information and another section to enter products. I would like to clear out the second section when user wants to enter more products. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're a mere hour away from hacking that clearForm function to suite your needs then, good luck ;]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
      $message = $user->register();
      $_POST['parameter1 in your form'] = "";
      $_POST['parameter2 in your form'] = "";
      $_POST['parameter3 in your form'] ="";
   }
```